# What is the functional role of CKY-I and CKY-R in ISAKMP (IKEv1)?

Tags: keys, reference-request

According to [RFC 2409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#section-3.2):

> CKY-I and CKY-R are the Initiator's cookie and the Responder's cookie, respectively, from the ISAKMP header.

Each CKY is a 64 bit value that is included in each [ISAKMP Header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2408#section-3.1) in the Phase1 and Phase2 negotiation, and future ISAKMP informational exchanges.  And they are also used in the [math for key generation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#page-10).

Also in the ISAKMP RFC, I see that the [Cookies are used to Identify the ISAKMP Security Association](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#page-6) (SA):

> Per the base ISAKMP document, the ISAKMP SA is identified by the Initiator's cookie followed by the Responder's cookie

<sup>*(although I'm not sure what "base ISAKMP document" they are referring to)*</sup>

Given all these describe *what* the CKY-I and CKY-R values are, I am curious to understand **why they exist**.  Effectively, **what is the functional role they play?**

If they solely exist to identify the SA, why not simply use an SPI value like IPsec does?  Or, why not simply pick a random arbitrary value to use and not include it in all the key material calculation?

**Bonus question:**  *“How”* are they created? I imagine they are random values, but I couldn't find any confirmation related to that in the RFCs.

Comment: @e-sushi thanks for the edits, looks much better now.

Comment: Nothing to thank me for… just fine-tuned some formatting. But thanks for thanking me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the functional role they play?

They exist to identify the SA.  That is, when an IKE implementation receives an IKE packet, it is able to use the cookies to identify the SA that the packet corresponds to.

> Why not simply use an SPI value like IPsec does?

Why do you think there is some fundamental difference between the cookies that IKE uses, and the SPI that IPSec uses?  They are essentially the same; they are an arbitrary identifier that the allows the implementation to correlate incoming packets with SAs.  Now, there are some minor differences; most notably that an IKE packet contains the identifiers from both sides, while an IPSec packet only contains the identifier from the receiving side; however that difference doesn't change what those identifiers signify.

> *how* are they created?

Actually, the RFCs do not specify how the implementation selects its cookies, and for a good reason; that is something for the implementation to decide, and if the implementation can (for example) speed up the lookup by selecting nonrandom values, it is free to do so.

Now, there is a minor glitch for IKE cookies that do not reply to IPSec SPIs; since both the initiator and the responder cookies are in the IKE packet, then if both sides select nonrandom cookies (and use the same strategy), then there is a possibility for the implementation to get confused (as it won't know apriori which cookie is his, at least if the implementation can be both an initiator and a responder.  This possibility also exists if the cookies are selected randomly; however the cookies that sufficiently long that such a collision is, in practice, improbable.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer Poncho!  That clears that up for me!

Answer (score 0):

Nonce Key and Cookie are the random values generated by both Initiator and responder.
These keys help in generating the Session Key IDs which will be ultimately used for encrypting the further IKE messages, encrypting the data plane (ESP) traffic, integrity check of data plane packets using HMAC.

The Session Key IDs that get generated on both the tunnel endpoints after the 4 messages are exchanged (MAIN MODE).
Session Key ID is a number created by a mathematical algorithm called “Pseudo-Random function (prf)”.  Below mentioned are the formulas of SKEYIDs.

SKEYID= prf (Pre Shared Key + Nonce Value of Initiator + Nonce Value of Responder).
This Session Key ID will be the same on both the IPSEC peers because both have the same preshared key and Nonce Values exchanged during the 3rd and 4th packet.
SKEYID_D= prf (SKEYID + Initiator Cookie sent in 1st packet + Responder Cookie sent in 2nd packet + Shared Secret generated by the Diffie Hellman algorithm after exchanging Public Keys in 3rd and 4th Message). This SKEYID_D will be used for encrypting and decrypting the data plane traffic encapsulated with ESP.
SKEYID_A= prf (SKEYID_D + SKEYID + Initiator Cookie + Responder Cookie + Shared Secret)
This SKEYID_A will be used for integrity check of data plane ESP packets as HMAC.

SKEYID_E= prf (SKEYID_A + SKEYID + Initiator Cookie + Responder Cookie + Shared Secret)
We know that there is a total of 9 packets get exchanged in IKEv1 to set up the tunnel for the data plane. As of now, 4 packets are exchanged which were unencrypted but from the 5th packet, all remaining packets will be encrypted. For encryption we need a key, This SKEYID_E will be used for encrypting ISAKMP Packet 5 to ISAKMP Packet 9.

[https://zindagitech.com/understanding-ipsec-ikev1-and-its-packets/#:~:text=Main%20Mode%20Message%2D1%3A%20The,message%20contains%20the%20Initiator%20cookie](https://zindagitech.com/understanding-ipsec-ikev1-and-its-packets/#:%7E:text=Main%20Mode%20Message%2D1%3A%20The,message%20contains%20the%20Initiator%20cookie).